# How to import all files from directory?

Tags: node.js

I need to import all files from directory in index.js via `fs.readdir()`

I found a solution. Thanks!

file1.js:

```
export default () => {
    console.log('file1.js is imported');
}
```

index.js:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => file !== 'index.js');      

const fileModules = {};

files.forEach(file => {
    const { name } = path.parse(file); 

    fileModules[name] = require(`./${name}`).default;
});

const { file1 } = fileModules;

file1();  // file1.js is imported
```

Comment: Are you getting some error?

Comment: Yes. ReferenceError: file1 is not defined

Comment: Well you have a require statement, but aren't actually defining file1 anywhere.

Comment: I tried - import name from `./${name}`; but it also do not work. How I need to define file1 in index.js?

Comment: @Denis You can't define members dynamically and `import` doesn't work unless it's at the top. You should `require` each module and assign it as a property of an object you create. For instance: `const fileModules = {}` and then your require: `fileModules[name] = require(\`./${name}\`)`

Comment: Thanks @Mikael Lennholm you helped me find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @thomann061 you helped me find a solution.